Reliable devnet airdrops
I've been having trouble with getting reliable airdrops of Devnet SOL. I've tried the solana CLI, and every faucet site I could find (they all error out/ say faucet is empty). Only QuickNode works, and even that is limited to once every 12 hours.
I'm using a Mac with an M1 chip, which means I can't run a local validator
Has anyone else faced similar issues? How do you manage to get a reliable source of SOL on Devnet? Any suggestions or workarounds would be greatly appreciated!

Check out this article which lists available faucets - https://solana.com/es/developers/guides/getstarted/solana-token-airdrop-and-faucets


faucet.solana.com - A public web faucet hosted by the Solana Foundation
SolFaucet.com - Web UI for airdrops from the public RPC endpoints
QuickNode - A web faucet operated by QuickNode


If the foundation faucets are empty ping solana_devs on twitter or wait for a while before they are refilled.
Solana releases do contain Apple silicon releases, what error do you get when running the solana-test-validator?
